# Conversion of date data type to datetime resulted to invalid date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatetime

I am trying to covert date value to datetime in SQL with the following query,which is resulting to invalid value:

*select convert(datetime,date_1, 25) from table1;*

**date_1(of data type date):** 2019-12-02

**expected o/p:** 2019-12-02 00:00:00.000

**actual o/p:** 1905-06-29 00:00:00.000

Can anyone please tell me the right method of converting date to datetime? and what's wrong with the method I tried?

Comment: Check your input value. This is working as expected for me.

Comment: The DATE datatype has a domain that far exceeds that of DATETIME. You will need to adjust for that in some fashion. Start by selecting all rows where date_1 (nice column name btw) < '17530101' (which is the lower domain boundary for datetime).

Comment: Try `convert(datetime,date_1, 23)`

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me:

```
select cast(date_1 as datetime)
```

Comment: SQL processing is a subject of some predefined rules, so it works for everyone regardless of the person running the statement. If you think this should work, please, describe why; if you have doubts - please, describe what *may be* dependent on *which* criteria.

Comment: If I remember well it depend on SQL server locale.
You can check your setting by running:

    DBCC USEROPTIONS;